# Different behaviour in BaKoMa TeX and MiKTeX

Tags: pdftex, miktex, bakoma

I am trying to use the [resume template by David Grant](http://www.davidgrant.ca/latex_resume_template).

I have put both the `.tex` file and the `shading.sty` file together in one folder.

When I use BakomaTeX (v 9.83) to convert the `.tex` file to PDF I get the shading regions perfectly fine

[image: fine]

but when I use TeXworks of MiKTeX on the same `.tex` file along with the `shading.sty` in the same folder, the output is

[image: bad]

Further, when I removed the `shading.sty` file from the folder, MiKTeX compilation failed indicating that the `shading.sty` file was being used. 
I need to get the shading even when I use MiKTeX to convert LaTeX to PDF.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think we could do with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for testing. In particular, it would be useful to see what file versions are in use: add `\listfiles` to the input and edit the results from the two compilations into your answer.

Comment: I get the desired output if I compile with the `DVI > PS > PDF` chain on the `.tex` file in your link. But I would second @JosephWright's suggestion for you to provide an MWE.

Comment: @hpesoj626 That was my other suspicion: difference in drivers due to a different route (not all code works with direct PDF output).

Comment: I don't use TeXWorks but looking at your second picture, I see that you start with `pdflatex`. Set up your TeXWorks compiler in this sequence: `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`. If you use `bibtex` and `makeindex`, set up something like `latex+makeindex+bibtex+latex+latex+dvips+ps2pdf`

Comment: Regarding your words in the end: When you removed `shading.sty` from compile folder, where did you put it? You must move it into a [local texmf root](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex). And did you make a FNDB refresh then? If not, that’s another reason, why MiKTeX failed, because there is no preshipped version of this package file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where does the texmf folder exists or do I need to create one ?

Comment: Regarding installation of custom packages in Windows, you can see [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows?rq=1) But regarding your problem, my cheap crystal ball says that it is more of a driver issue. It is even clear in my crystal ball that it says so in `shading.sty` that you need to call on a `\PScommands` "before any of the shading routines can be used". This is done by running PostScript.

Comment: Same crystal ball says that your BakomaTeX is configured to run through a `DVI > PS > PDF` routine. `:)`

Comment: @hpesoj626 - Thanks for your help...but I am relatively new to latex...Could you please help me understand what does the line "The TeX command \PScommands must be called before any of the % shading routines can be used" mean....Where and how do I use pscommands to achieve what I want ?

Comment: The definition of `\PScommands` is found at the last part of `shadings.sty`. But regarding how to set up TeXWorks so that it compiles through the `DVI > PS > PDF` sequence, I am sorry but I can't help there as I don't use TeXWorks. You can run these commands through the terminal though if you want. Do the sequence: `latex resume.tex`, `dvips resume.dvi` and `ps2pdf resume.ps`

Comment: @hpesoj626 - Thanks a lot....the last 3 commands worked perfect...Did exactly what I wanted...Thanks again!!  :)

Comment: AFAIK BaKoMa does not include pdfTeX (I would be quite surprised if it did, since pdfTeX is GPL and BaKoMa is closed source).

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this answer for the sake of closure. I don't use BaKoMa TeX but with MiKTeX installed, you can compile your document through the `latex > dvips > ps2pdf` sequence in your terminal. To do this, open your terminal/command line and go to your working directory. Then run the following commands. Change `myfile` to the name of your file.

```
latex myfile
dvips myfile
ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

As mentioned by Joseph Wright in comment, some differences in output are caused by running different drivers. In the case of `shadings.sty`, the following comment can be seen at the end of the file:

```
% Here are some simple PostScript routines.
%
% The TeX command \PScommands must be called before any of the
% shading routines can be used.
```

If you don't want to use the terminal for compiling your document, you can set up TeXWorks to compile your document through the `latex > dvips > ps2pdf` sequence. I don't use TeXWorks but most text editors can be set up to execute this compiling sequence.

I suspect that BaKoMa TeX follows a similar procedure albeit using proprietary drivers.